# Convergence in the $L^2$ sense but NOT pointwise.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, partial-differential-equations

Let

$$f_n(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
1 \quad \mbox{ if $\frac12 - \frac1n \leq x \leq \frac12 + \frac1n$,} \\
0 \quad \mbox{otherwise} \\ 
\end{array} 
\right. $$

on the interval $[0,1]$.

How do I show that $f_n \to 0$ in the $L^2$ sense but NOT pointwise.

Comment: What is the integral of $f_n^2$?  Does $f_n\to 0$ for $x=1/2$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$
\|f_n\|_{L^2}^2= \int_{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}} 1^2 \, dx = \frac{2}{n}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. I can see that as $n \to \infty$, $f_n \to 0$. In my textbook, the definition says that the sequence converges to $f(x)$ in the $L^2 $sense on $I$ if $
\|f_n(x)-f(x)\|_{L^2} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$
If $I=[a,b]$, stating that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ in the $L^2$ sense is equivalent to saying that $\int_{b}^{a} [f_n(x)-f(x)]^2dx \to 0 as n \to \infty .$ What would be $f(x)$?

Comment: @KBG In this case, $f =0$ in the $L^2$ sense.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $f_n$ does not converge pointwise to $0$ it is enough to notice that $f_{n}(1/2)=1$ for all $n$.

But you can show that $f_n(x)\to0$ as $n\to \infty$ for all $x\neq 1/2$ where $x\in [0,1]$.